# How to specify path to custom package without whole path name on install

Tags: r

I can't figure out what the issue is here.

I have created my package and I am now trying to make sure it is well written etc.

To do this I am using '[goodpractice](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/goodpractice/versions/1.0.1)' package.
I run it as follows:

```
gp("MyPackageR")
```

and it says:

```
Preparing: covr
Error: `path` is invalid: MyPackageR
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path) : path[1]="MyPackageR": No such file or directory
```

so then I run it as:

```
gp("~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/MyPackageR")
```

and it runs but this time when it gets to my tests folder in which I specify a file path as follows: `load(file="./data/PathDataFrameFinal.rda")` again it trips up with the error:

```
cannot open compressed file './data/PathDataFrameFinal.rda', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

I think this must be a problem with the file path of my package and I would like the filepath to be so that I can specify the package name without the absolute path of its location. How can I do that?

The getwd() is `"/home/rstudio/MyPackageR"`

Comment: I don't know the package but may it be that `gp` looks in some other R directory? like `"~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/"` or so

Comment: See `?system.file`